# Bash Script in AWS codedeploy is not executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I tried to deploy an api service from github to ec2 via code deploy, code from github is transferred to the appropriate lo location but when i try to execute the bash script it is failing

> appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/Gritly-backend-v2
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: build.sh
      timeout: 400
      runas: root
```

> build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/Gritly-backend-v2
docker build . -t gritly_backend -f Dockerfile.dev
docker stop gritly_backend
docker rm gritly_backend
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name gritly_backend gritly_backend
OUTPUT=$(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc | wc -l)
if [ ${OUTPUT} != 0 ];
then    
    docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
fi
```

> Error

```
LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - build.sh
[stderr]bash: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/4ceeb37e-1874-4290-9e55-a92d655d1558/d-G03KT19HJ/deployment-archive/build.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

> tried to run sh build.sh

```
: No such file or directory/ec2-user/Gritly-backend-v2
: no such file or directoryunable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ec2-user/Gritly-backend-v2/Dockerfile.dev
Error response from daemon: No such container: gritly_backend
Error: No such container: gritly_backend
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
build.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - build.sh
[stderr]bash: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/4ceeb37e-1874-4290-9e55-a92d655d1558/d-G03KT19HJ/deployment-archive/build.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like the file might have windows line endings. Try running `dos2unix` on the file